# spark streaming keep generating stages when using reduceByKey

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

It seems to generate empty stages when using function that increase partitions the same thing happens when calling repartition, the stages overflow the spark UI and i cant track the real stages, it makes the UI useless

I get the same behavior from the word count example
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaNetworkWordCount.java

I use spark 1.1.0 with default settings

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Which Spark version you use? Provide the code you used or at least simplified version of it? Don't you mix stages with tasks? Which is the settings of the streaming you use (batch interval, spark.streaming.blockInterval, number of receivers)?

Comment: I refering to the completed stages table in the ui without sending data to the socket spark keep adding entries to the table

Answer (score 1):

With the Spark Streaming you are processing stream of data. With the example you attached it works in a batches of data each 1 second:

```
JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(1));
```

This means that each 1 second you have a separate RDD created inside of DStream and all the transformations are performed. This causes the fact that you see in the WebUI many separate stages executing one by one - it is the transformations executed on top of each separate input batch

Amount of partitions created in the batch RDD inside of DStream can be calculated as `batch interval / spark.streaming.blockInterval` which with default settings would give you 1 additional partition each 200ms. Try increasing the batch interval to 1 minute or at least 30 seconds and you would see this better - almost each line you entered in the `nc` would be translated to a separate partition, and separate partition causes scheduling of a separate task to process it, this is why some of the stages would have more than 1 task.

Comment: But why does it add new stages every second when theres no data when i use reducebykey and when i use only map it add stages only when theres data

Comment: because even for empty RDD it executes at least one task. You can simply start Spark shell (I prefer PySpark) and execute something simple: `sc.parallelize([]).map(lambda x: (x,y)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y).collect()` - you will see it would have 2 stages with 1 task each